# Accessing image files + file browsing in Android

Tags: android, file-io

I'm using HTC Dream and trying to read the images stored in the "default" album folder of this phone. But I've yet to found out what's the folder path to those images file.

When I mount the phone to my comp, some of the default images are in: 
/E0FD-1813/DCIM/
and the photos taken using the phone are stored in 
/E0FD-1813/DCIM/100MEDIA/

But using those paths, accessing the images throws a "No Such File" error.

So

1. do you know what's the path to that image folder? What would be the path patterns (if any) in other Android phones?
2. I don't need to set any additional permission to access those files, do I?
3. Do you know how I can build a "file browsing" widget in my activity? I've searched and seems like there is no such widget and I've to install app that does file browsing. In any case, how to incorporate that as a file-browsing view in my current activity?

Thanks for your kind advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I've yet to found out what's the folder path to those images file.

There is no single folder.

> do you know what's the path to that image folder?

There is no single folder. Use the `MediaStore` content provider.

Comment: With regards to the file path I mentioned, it's in sdcard and the path to load the file is: /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/<file_name>